# How to check if a value is in a sequence of values?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have the following:

```
<xsl:when test="(PropertyType[@PropertyType=1]) 
                and ($year - YearBuild  &lt; 3)"
 >New</xsl:when>
```

I want to test for several PropertyType attribute numbers, and not only for 1, for instance, in the above example I check if the attribute *PropertyType* of the element *PropertyType* is equals to 1, I want to check if it: equals to 1 or 2, or 10 or 11 or .... (a list of numbers) how to?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to test if some scalar value belongs to a sequence.

In XPath 1.0 (without sequence data type):

```
PropertyType[contains(' 1 2 10 11 ',concat(' ',@PropertyType,' ')]
```

In XPath 2.0 (with sequence data type):

```
PropertyType[@PropertyType = (1,2,10,11)]
```

**Note**: Existencial comparison.